# How do I use the python-decorator package to decorate classmethods?

Tags: python, decorator, class-method, python-decorators

I'm have a decorator that I want to use to decorate class methods. In the following example, the @mydec decorator works fine on its own, however it does not preserve the function signature when using help() or pydoc. In order to fix this, I looked at using @decorator python-decorator package:

```
import functools
import decorator


@decorator.decorator
def mydec(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def inner(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        # do some stuff
        return func(cls, *args, **kwargs)
    return inner


class Foo(object):
    @classmethod
    @mydec
    def bar(cls, baz='test', qux=None):
        print (baz, qux)


Foo.bar()
```

Unfortunately, this results in the following exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/test.py", line 21, in <module>
    Foo.bar()
  File "<string>", line 2, in bar
TypeError: mydec() takes exactly 1 argument (4 given)
```

Comment: Have you tried reversing the decorators order?

Comment: @OfirIsrael: it is the `mydec` decorator that is the problem, not the ordering.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You do not need to provide your own wrapper anymore, just use `@decorator.decorator` on the *inner* function, which takes one extra first positional argument, the function wrapped:

```
@decorator.decorator
def mydec(func, cls, *args, **kwargs):
    # do some stuff
    return func(cls, *args, **kwargs)
```

The `decorator` package doesn't use a closure for decorators and instead passes in the wrapped function as an argument.

Demo:

```
>>> @decorator.decorator
... def mydec(func, cls, *args, **kwargs):
...     # do some stuff
...     return func(cls, *args, **kwargs)
... 
>>> class Foo(object):
...     @classmethod
...     @mydec
...     def bar(cls, baz='test', qux=None):
...         print (baz, qux)
... 
>>> Foo.bar()
('test', None)
```

Comment: Ah, I had misunderstood how to use. That definitely makes decorators cleaner. Thanks!